# Embed SonarQube analysis in development process

Tags: sonarqube

In our agile dev team we're always working on multiple features at the same time.
We're using Git flow as a branching model and each feature gets its own feature branch, (parent = develop).

What we are looking for is a good way to embed SonarQube (v6.2 for us right now) analysis (for Java) in our development proces, such that:

- We get SonarQube feedback (eg. new introduced issues) *before* starting the test on the feature branch. Meaning before merging back to develop.
- We want only 1 SonarQube project, not multiple, such that we can monitor deltas in issues correctly.
- It is very possible that the features touch the same classes

SonarQube does not handle multiple branches properly, it handles them as separate projects.

**Does anyone have an idea on how to embed SonarQube in a process like this?**

One option we have is create a separate *sonar* Git branch, in which feature branches are merged and on which the analysis is done, but that feels like useless more work and still leaves us with the problem of not being able to cancel a feature at any point before final acceptance.

Comment: The next LTS (6.7) will bring branch support: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-253

Comment: That is good news. I've read earlier that the next LTS version will gain multibranch support, but I couldn't find which version that would be.

How do you know that 6.7 will get the multibranch support, the Jira ticket does not specify that...

Got any insights on when 6.7 is planned to be released? :)

Comment: The [Versions page of SonarQube](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:versions-panel) shows the planned dates of upcoming releases.